# Starting to contribute on Github

Tags: github

I've been programming for a career and as a hobby for more than two years now. I want to start contributing to some projects on Git hub, but I'm not sure where to start. What advice do you have for me for first starting out on Git hub?

Answer (score 1):

If you use projects hosted on Github in your programming, you'll eventually encounter typos and mistakes in documentation. Fixing these is an excellent way to get started with contributing.

Comment: I'm assuming that any testing paradigm they use will be specified in their documentation? It would seem unfair to require testing and not specify which paradigm or framework to use.

Comment: If you're just fixing typos, you won't have to worry about testing. If you make code changes then there are usually contribution guidelines or the maintainer will point out changes to make and ways to add tests.